On the compactness of the square of a finite double norm integration operator $T$ on $L^1 (\mu)$.
Good morning everyone,
I have read in S. P. Eveson, Compactness Criteria for Integral Operators in L∞ and L1 Spaces, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 123, 1995, 3709-3716 :
"If $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a positive measure space, $k: S \times S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, and $p, q > 1$ with $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, one may define the `double norm' of $k$ on $L^p(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ by
$$
\|k\|^p = \int_S \left( \int_S |k(s, t)|^q \, d\mu(t) \right)^{p/q} \, d\mu(s).
$$
If this double-norm is finite, then the integral operator induced by $k$ is a compact transformation on $L^p(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ (see Zaanen, "Linear Analysis" [6, Chapter 11, §2, Example D]).
One may make the obvious generalisations of the double-norm to the spaces $L^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $L^\infty(S, \Sigma, \mu)$, but in these cases integral operators of finite double-norm, although bounded, are not necessarily compact. In the case of an integral operator $T$ of finite double-norm on $L^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$, $T^2$ turns out to be compact ([6, Chapter 11, §2, Example E])."
I would like to have the proof that $T^2$ is compact in this case, and eventually if we consider that the $L^1$ spaces are different: operator from $L^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ to $L^1(S', \Sigma', \mu')$. But Zaanen's book is a bit old and difficult to access. Does someone have an idea of the proof or another reference?
Thank you very much for your help,

Do you mean you don't have a copy of Zane's or that you can't understand his presentation of Example E?

I am looking for the proof that T^2 is compact. The proof is apparently in Zaanen "Linear Analysis". But I don't have it. So either a proof or an accessible reference would be perfect

Hi @thibaultjeannin, I think this posting may be of interest to you. It shows that the dual of $K$ as defined in your problem is also compact for $1<p<\infty$. This will also carry to the dual of $K\circ K$ when $p=1$ which acts on $(L_1(\mu))^*\supset L_\infty(\mu)$.

Hi @Mittens very interesting indeed! I will continue my research in the very specific case where mu and mu' are probability measures and 0<= k(x,y)<=1. Thanks you very much for your help!

@Mittens To conclude our discussion : a weakly compact operator from L1(mu) to L1(mu') cannot bee surjective, otherwise L1(mu') would be reflexive, see "SOME CHARACTERIZATIONS OF SURJECTIVE
OPERATORS ON BANACH LATTICES". Using your arguments, I prove weakly compactness and non surjectivity in my particular problem. Thanks you very much!!!

Is the double norm really a norm?

The proof that I know relies on the Eberlein-Smulain theorem, and to be more precise, on the Dunford-Pettois theorem. The issue is that to determine compactness of operators on Banach spaces, it is often easier to look weak compactness. In $L_1$ weak-compactness is related to uniform integrability, which is not a trivial sort of result.
Here I present a solution based on a series of problems that I worked on in my graduate student  days.
In Zaanen's,  the assumption is that $(S,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is separable, that is, there is accountable family of integrable sets $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathscr{S}$ and that $S=\bigcup_nC_n$ for some $C_n\in\mathcal{C}$. This in particular, implies that $L_1(\mu)$ (in fact any $L_p(\mu)$ with $1\leq p<\infty$) is separable. This, in the case $1<p<\infty$,  implies that any ball $B(0;a)$ in $L_p(\mu)$ is metrizable in $\sigma(L_p(\mu),L_q(\mu))$.
For the case $p=1$ we only assume $\sigma$-finiteness. Thus,  it is enough to consider the case where $\mu$ is finite. The main assumption on $T$ is that $C=\int_X\|T(x,\cdot)\|_{L_\infty(\mu)}\,\mu(dx)<\infty$.
Now, consider the ball $B(0;a)\subset L_1(\mu)$.  Then
$$ |Tf(x)|\leq\|T(x,\cdot)\|_{L_\infty(\mu)}\|f\|_{L_1(\mu)}$$
and so $\mathcal{F}=\{Tf:f\in B(0;a)\}$ is uniform integrable, that is,

$\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $L_1(\mu)$ and
For any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies that
$$\sup_{h\in\mathcal{F}}\int_A|h|\,d\mu<\varepsilon. $$

Since $L_1(\mu)$ is finite (or $\sigma$-finte), $(L_1(\mu))^*=L_\infty(\mu)$. By the Dunford-Pettis theorem, $\mathcal{F}$ has compact closure in the weak topology $\sigma(L_1(\mu),L_\infty(\mu))$, and by the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, $\mathcal{F}$ is in fact $\sigma(L_1(\mu),L_\infty(\mu))$-sequentially compact. Hence, for any sequence $(h_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset\mathcal{F}$, there is a subsequence $h_{n_k}$ and a function $h_0$ such that $h_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}h_0$ in $\sigma(L_1(\mu),L_\infty(\mu))$.
We may assume without loss of generality that for all $x\in S$, $T_x:y\mapsto T(x,y)$ is in $L_\infty(\mu)$. Let $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset B(0;a)$ and let $h_n=Tf_n$. By the arguments above, there is a subsequence $h_{n_k}$ and a function $h_0\in L_1(\mu)$ such that
$$g_k(x):=T^2f_{n_k}(x)=\int_S T(x,y) h_{n_k}(y)\,\mu(dy)\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_S T(x,y) h_0(y)\,\mu(dy)=: g_0(x)$$
Since $T$ maps $L_1(\mu)$ into $L_1(\mu)$, $g_0,g_k\in :_1(\mu)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, outside a set of $\mu$-measure $0$,
$$|g_k(x)-g_0(x)|\leq \|T(x,\cdot)\|_{L_\infty(\mu)}\|h_{n_k}-h_0\|_{L_1(\mu)}\leq (a+\|h_0\|_1)\|T(x,\cdot)\|_{L_\infty(\mu)}\in L_1(\mu)$$
By dominated convergence
$$\|g_k-g_0\|_{L_1(\mu)}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0$$
All this shows that $T^2(B(0;a))$ is sequentially compact in $L_1(\mu)$ and thus compact; therefore, $T^2$ is a compact operator.

Comments:

The key ingredients of the proof is the Dunford-Pettis theorem that states that in a $\sigma$--finite measure space $(S,\mathscr{S},\mu)$, a set $K\subset L_1(\mu)$ is $\sigma(L_1(\mu),L_\infty(\mu))$ compact (and also sequentially compact) iff the set $K$ is uniformly integrable.

The book of Zaanen proves a version of Dunford-Pettis theorem as a Lemma in the presentation of Example E in Chapter 11, §2. It also provides an example, due to von Neumann, that $T$ may fail to be compact when $p=1$.

For a treatment of the Dunford-Pettis theorem, based on the Eberlien-Smulian theorem one can check Bogachev, V. I., Measure Theory, Vol I, Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg, 2007, pp. 285-286.

@PhoemueX provides here a much simpler example of an operator $T$ of the type described above in which $T$ which fails to be compact: Fix $g\in L^+_1((\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)\setminus\{0\}$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Define
$$T(x,y)=g(x)\sum_{n\geq0}\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}(y)e^{inx}$$
Then $\|T(x,\cdot)\|_\infty\leq g(x)\in L_1$. Notice that
$$T\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}(x)=g(x) e^{in x}, \qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$$
converges to $0$ in $\sigma(L_1(\lambda),L_\infty(\lambda))$ (by virtue of the Riemann-Lebegue lemma). As $\|\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}\|_1=1$ and $\|T\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}\|_1=\|g\|_1>0$, $T$ cannot be compact.



Thank you very much. It is very clear. In fact, I use the compactness of T^2 to get the non-surjectivity of T. If we consider T: L^1(S, mu) to L^1(S', mu'), would you know or have an idea, if we still have non-surjectivity? It might be a lot to ask. Thank you very much for your help! Have an excellent day.

@thibaultjeannin: The compactness of $T^2=T\circ T$ would imply that $T^2$ is not surjective by virtue of the open map theorem see here. In turn, this precludes the possibility of $T$ being surjective, for if it were, so would $T^2$ be.

Yes it is my idea. But if we consider the same condition on the kernel (or even a stronger hypothesis) but the departure L1 space and L1 arrrival space are note the same, can we say something about surjectivity?

Since we can no more use the compactness argument as such

@thibaultjeannin: I could not understand your last question. It seems that you are interested in the case where $T$ is $(S,\mathscr{S},\mu)\otimes(S',\mathscr{S}',\mu')$ measurable and $|T(x,\cdot)|{L\infty(\mu)}\in L_1(\mu')$. In this case, the operator induced by $T$ maps $L_1(\mu)$ into $L_1(\mu')$. The composition $T\circ T$ is then not defined. Whether $T$ can be compact or surjective in such situations escapes me. But it would not be difficult to show examples in which $T$ is not surjective.

@thibaultjeannin: It is worth mentioning that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are integral operators of the type discussed in the problem ($x\mapsto |T_j(x,\cdot)|{L\infty(\mu)}\in L_1(\mu)$), then a slight modification of the proof I presented yields that $T_2\circ T_1$ is also compact as an operator on $L_1(\mu)$.
